# How do you request the Azure Resource Management endpoint scope correctly with MSAL?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

So I read that if you add .default at the end of a resource URI in a scope it would return us a a proper v1 token. When setting the protectedResourceMap for MSAL what exactly should the scope be? 'https://management.azure.com/.default' doesn't seem to work. Nor does 'https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation'.

What is the proper way to setup the scope so when requesting consent to our app they approve the Azure management APIs?

Comment: If you're looking for resource URI try `https://management.core.windows.net/`.

Comment: @RohitSaigal management.core.windows.net is for classic deployed resources. All modern ARM based resources are at the new management.azure.com endpoint. Aren't they entirely different scopes?

Comment: `https://management.core.windows.net/` corresponds to `Windows Azure Service Management API`. The reason I mentioned it for you was, I came across a sample on Microsoft Docs which talks about building a web app that asks user to grant access to Azure Resource Manager.. and for acquiring token the sample uses the above mentioned resource URI. Here is the specific link.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-api-authentication#get-app-only-access-token-for-azure-resource-manager also take a look at the diagram at the top of this page.

Answer (score 4):

**Use two slashes like this:**

```
https://management.core.windows.net//.default
```

"*This is because the ARM API expects a slash in its audience claim (aud), and then there is a slash to separate the API name from the scope.*"

Source:
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Adal-to-Msal

Here's a complete example:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var tenantId = "<tenantId>";
    var clientId = "<clientId>";
    var clientSecret = "<clientSecret>";

    var credentials = GetCredentials(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    Console.WriteLine(credentials);
}

public static async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetCredentials(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
{
    string authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/";
    IConfidentialClientApplication app;
    app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                                              .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                                              .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
                                              .Build();

    IEnumerable<string> scopes = new List<string>() { "https://management.core.windows.net//.default" };
    var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
          .ExecuteAsync();
    return result;
}
```

Screenshot of the AuthenticationResult object in LINQPad:
[image: Screenshot of the AuthenticationResult object in LINQPad]

Sample code from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-netcore-daemon